# Winform Combobox with DataSource as List<int>

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource

This may be a very simple question but I realized I could not get it work.

I have a Winform combo box with datasource as a `List<int>`

```
combo.DataSource = intList;
```

What do I put for `.DisplayMember` and `.ValueMember` in order to simply have a list of integer values? Not setting them will display nothing.

I have worked with other `List<myObj>` in which `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are myObj's properties. How about simple data type like `int`, `string`?

When retrieving the selected item, one could simply cast `(int)(combo.SelectedItem)` or have to go through the property corresponding to `ValueMember`?

Comment: Without setting the DisplayMember and ValueMember it should work. Have you tried simply assigning "" for both values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not occur because you have a list of integers, it probably occurs because you add items to the list *after* assigning it to the `.DataSource` property. List does not have a mechanism to notify its container when items are added to or removed from it.

Either add items to the list *before* assigning it to the `.DataSource` property, or use a wrapper like [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as Krishnraj Rana suggested.

Comment: You were right. I did not rebind after modifying the underlying list. And I kept thinking it's the problem with List<int> and DisplayMember.

Comment: On the other hand, normally every time after modifying the list I need to rebind : 
Bindingsource bsource = new BindingSource();
bsource.DataSource = listInt;
combo.DataSource = bsource;
combo.Invalidate();
Is it the correct way to do it?

Comment: @Kenny If you use BindingSource, then you should modify the BindingSource instead of the underlying list. Besides, combo.Invalidate() should be required.

Answer (score 2):

Here [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) comes into picture. You can use it like this.

```
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
combo.DataSource = bSource;
```

Though you can set datasource of combobox directly with list. like this -

```
combo.DataSource = intList;
```

This also works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add items from list using foreach like this.

```
foreach (var v in intList)
{
   comboBox1.Items.Add(v.ToString());
}
```